# Navigator "context" undifined name in Navigator.push

Tags: dart, flutter, navigation

says Undefined name 'context' in Navigator.push. 
If i put context in Navigator.push it says that context is undefined name.
Even after importing the required file it does not seem to work the way i it should.

```
Widget btn() {
    if (index == 0) {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Exp());
            Navigator.push(context,route);
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
          elevation: 4.0,
          label: Text(
            'Skip',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.pink),
          ),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
            color: Colors.pink,
            size: 30.0,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else if (index == 2) {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: ()=>null,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
          elevation: 4.0,
          label: Text(
            'Explore',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.pink),
          ),
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
            color: Colors.pink,
            size: 30.0,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Text('');
    }
  }
```

Comment: You must pass the BuildContext of the Widget Tree where you are using this widget. Add a BuildContext parameter to the constructor and then pass the context to it when you use the btn widget.

Comment: And you need to also subclass your widget from StatelessWidget or StatefullWidget